# How to correct misspelling in column and collapse values into correct row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I'm rather new to R and struggling through data tidying. I have a problem, where I don't find an answer to, but maybe I'm searching with the wrong terms.

I have a table (`df_samples`) in the following format:

| species | gender | group | sample1 | sample2 | sample n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| penguin | m | i. | 20 | 21 | n |
| penguin | f | i. | NA | 18 | n |
| lion | m | ii. | 5 | 4 | n |
| lion | f | ii. | 2 | 9 | n |
| penguin | f | ii. | 22 | NA | n |
| tiger | m | ii. | 7 | 6 | n |
| tiger | f | ii. | 6 | 8 | n |

Now, the problem here is the penguin with group ii. which is wrong and should be i. In my table there are several hundred different species and samples. I have this problem with several rows, where species have the wrong group.

I was able to find the specific rows with the problems using the following code:

```
n_occur <- data.frame(table(df_samples$species))
df_samples_2 <- df_samples[df_samples$species %in% n_occur$Var1[n_occur$Freq > 2],]
```

This gives me the problematic rows and I can view them in an own dataframe. There I am able identify the rows with the mistakes and could correct them. But I have two problems where I'm stuck.

First I don't know how to index the problematic value to change it directly in my original data frame.

Second I have no idea how to bring the data stored in the row with the mistake to the "correct" row.

I am sure, there are answers on the web, but I am really struggling to express my problem in a way, which allows me to find them.

I would be grateful if somebody is able to help, either by pointing out how to search or by solving the problem.

Comment: How do you determine whether `i.` or `ii.` is the correct group?

Comment: I was doing it "by hand" but I think i could produce a list with the correct values.

Comment: if you have a list or a dataframe of correct values, you can just use `mutate()` and `case_when()`, if you add your list to this question I can show you how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways for this.

## Assume all species have the same group

If all species belong to the same group, you can use a vector that stores the `species` and `group` information to replace the current group.

Again, this will replace **ALL** `group`s within the same `species`.

#### base R

```
correct_group <- c("penguin" = "i.", "tiger" = "ii.", "lion" = "ii.")

df$group <- correct_group[match(df$species, names(correct_group))]
```

#### dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(group = correct_group[match(species, names(correct_group))])
```

## If you are doing it by hand:

We can also do it one by one if the species do not belong to the same group (only if you have a few records to change).

First identify the row index where `species` is "penguin" and `group` is "ii.". This is the record that you would like to change. Then simply replace the `group` value with "i.".

#### base R

```
df[which(df$species == "penguin" & df$group == "ii."), "group"] <- "i."
```

#### dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(group = ifelse(species == "penguin" & group == "ii.", "i.", group))
```

### Output

All of the above methods produce the same output.

```
species gender group sample1 sample2 sample.n
1 penguin      m    i.      20      21        n
2 penguin      f    i.      NA      18        n
3    lion      m   ii.       5       4        n
4    lion      f   ii.       2       9        n
5 penguin      f    i.      22      NA        n
6   tiger      m   ii.       7       6        n
7   tiger      f   ii.       6       8        n
```

**Remember for the `dplyr` methods, you have to "save" the `df` back to it (`df <- df %>% dplyr::method`), otherwise, it will only output the results to the console without actually changing anything.**

Comment: Thanks! I managed to correct the group numbers by matching with a correct list. But how do I bring together the data for penguin f. which is now separated in two different rows (should be in 1)?

Comment: Next time it's better to include the desired output in your question, so that we can provide the most accurate solution in one go :) Here's the code: `df %>% mutate(group = ifelse(species == "penguin" & group == "ii.", "i.", group)) %>% group_by(species, gender) %>% mutate(across(c(sample1, sample2), ~replace_na(.x, max(.x, na.rm = T))))`. Note that the `df` is your original `df`, so that we will first replace the wrong group, then "combine" the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using your process you can try the following steps.

Add unique ID to the rows so that it can be filtered later.

```
df_samples<-df_samples %>% 
  rowid_to_column()
```

Remove problem rows from df_samples based on the rowid in df_samples_2

```
df_samples<-df_samples[-df_samples_2$rowid,]
```

Update df_samples_2 as per your requirements, row by row mutates based on rowid.

Merge corrected rows back to df_samples

```
df_samples<-bind_rows(df_samples,df_samples_2)
```

Also if your end goal & data is as mentioned above you could also try this on your original df_samples

```
df_samples <-df_samples %>% 
  group_by(species) %>%  #this will create internal groups
  arrange(species,group) %>%  # Will ensure i. will be before ii.
  mutate(group=lag(group,default=first(group))) # lag() will copy earlier row values to current row per group.
```